# Selenium, Java, Maven, PhantomJS + TeamCity

Tags: java, maven, selenium, phantomjs, teamcity

I've got a project in Selenium/Java with tests that normally run on chromedriver.exe (I work on Windows) - no problems at all.

I have recently decided to add the project to our TeamCity that runs on Linux and since it cannot run tests on a browser, I want to switch to PhantomJS driver.

I've tried multiple variations of all the solutions I've found online and still can't get it working.
Currently I've got the phantomjs binary file in my resources, and I get the driver like this in an enum class:

```
PHANTOMJS {
    @Override
    public WebDriver initNewDriver() {
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", ClassLoader.getSystemResource(RELATIVE_PATH_TO_FILE_IN_RESOURCES).getFile());
        return new PhantomJSDriver();
    }
```

Then in the test class I start with driver.get(SOME_URL) - which is the furthest it ever got.

No matter what I do, when I tried to run it on TeamCity through 'clean test', I get something like this:

> [userLoginTest] java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /opt/buildAgent1/work/c4641c7cfd3331f7/web/drivers/phantomjslinux/phantomjs
>   [14:41:41]
>   [userLoginTest] java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /opt/buildAgent1/work/c4641c7cfd3331f7/web/drivers/phantomjslinux/phantomjs
>       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:518)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:123)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.findPhantomJS(PhantomJSDriverService.java:254)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:190)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.(PhantomJSDriver.java:104)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.(PhantomJSDriver.java:94)
>       at test.core.base.SeleniumDriver$3.initNewDriver(SeleniumDriver.java:47)
>       at test.core.base.TestBase.(TestBase.java:25)

I don't really understand TeamCity well and it's difficult to find solutions that are applicable to my project and that I actually understand. So any help is welcome. Thanks :)

Comment: does this path exist RELATIVE_PATH_TO_FILE_IN_RESOURCES ? is there a phantomjs binary in it? is it compitible with the machine you are using ? does it has proper permission for whatever user you are running TeamCity?

Comment: Yes, it's a path to phantomjs binary file. TeamCity runs on Linux, version 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 and I believe all the permissions are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by running `npm install phantomjs` on the server and using PhantomJS from there.